Windows-10 search files and files in sub-folders for text using FIle Explorer
I am using Windows 10.0.19045.4894, I want to recursively search the file contents for a string that with content:! .
It seems that this has some meaning because when I try this it brings up lots of results none of which contain the text I'm searching for, for example I want to look for content:!DB, but this isn't found in the text instead it brings up lots of results that contain DB.
I've also tried entering content:!DB, that doesn't bring up anything at all.  To be clear the question is, how do I search files including files in sub-folders for text that I enter, which starts with !

not really an answer but just my two pennies:
on some occasion when windows was just not able to provide the info I was looking for, I ended up using Agent Ransack ( website: https://www.mythicsoft.com/?src=abt  as of now it may be installed/used 100% free for personal use)

Explorer is indeed pretty inflexible with its query tokenization. I usually use grep or Total Commander for this type of searching, but PowerShell's Select-String cmdlet can recursively search in files and seems to respect the pattern you pass to it. Select-String -Path "*" -Pattern "!DB"
